# Windows 7 Install Stuck at Setup is Starting

Tags: windows-7

Well, funny story. I got a virus and when trying to remove it, my anti-virus software deleted something vital in windows vista, now nothing on my computer operates, it can't even boot up properly.

So I thought, "I'll go buy Windows 7, the operating system installation still works." I bought Windows 7, inserted the disk, selected the language options. I went to the next step and it said "Setup is Starting" I waited 15 minutes before looking again and it was still there, another two hours went by and I thought, "This ain't going to work, i'll look it up in google"

The main messege i've been seeing is "Disable Floppy Disk in BIOS". So I started BIOS and noticed there's no floppy disk options, so I don't have floppy disk feature on my laptop. So instead, I disabled any other things which may be causes this error, everything apart from the CD Rom/DVD Rom. Yet, it still didn't work. So this is really starting to irritate me, I wouldn't like to take it to a PC shop and be ripped off for something which I could find on the internet.

If anyone of you could give me tips on getting round this problem, it'd be much appreciated.

Specs:

- BIOS Version: D3A91
- CPU Type: Intel (R) Core (TM)2 Duo
  CPU T5250
- CPU Speed: 1500 MHz
- L2 Cacge RAM: 2048 KB
- Total Memory: 2048MB
- Slot 1: 1024MB
- Slot 2: 1024MB

Comment: Are you able to somehow blank the hard drive (like remove the old partitions).  I've seen older version of windows get stuck like this reading corrupted file systems.

Comment: What Coding Gorilla said - format the drive completely, the MBR is probably corrupt.  (The next step after 'Setup is Starting' is the license agreement and then the drive selections so presumably it's hanging ennumerating the drives.)

Comment: Would I be able to do that via the current computer? I have another working one, but I don't fancy changing the HDDs around

Comment: What make and model PC is it?

Comment: It's an Advent laptop, not too sure on the model.

Answer (score 1):

Use [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) or [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) to format or delete the required partitions.

**Edit:** Found you another solution [SuperFdisk](http://www.ptdd.com/manual2.htm)

Comment: That's not compatible for windows vista I don't think.

Comment: try Gparted instead, do you have a Windows XP cd I always use that to format partitions just in case I am not able to reach the partition wizard in Windows 7

Comment: I use Gparted for this all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You should :

1. Boot off the Windows 7 DVD
2. Delete the system partition and any other partitions that you are sure that you don't need
3. Create a new partition on the entire unused space
4. Install Windows 7 in the created partition after formatting it.

Ensure first that you can reinstall any software you need (serials and installation files), including drivers for all devices that are not automatically recognized by Windows 7, and that you have backups of any data you may need from the system partition.

Comment: How do I reformat though? Only thing I can do on my computer currently is run operating system setups. None of the repair things works.

Comment: Don't repair - install as new. When installing you get a screen with all partitions asking where to install. To format press "Drive options (advanced)". See "Custom option" in http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Installing-and-reinstalling-Windows-7.

Comment: I can't get to that screen though. The only options I can access are the keyboard and language settings. When I press repair, it doesn't load to anything

Comment: @Craig: You can't repair. You must reinstall. You can try to install as an "upgrade" which will refresh Windows without killing other installed products. Or you can install as new, losing all installed products but not your non-Windows data. Reformatting (lose everything) is normally counseled after a serious infection. Get help if this is too heavy.

Comment: No, what I'm trying to say is. I can't get to any upgrade/fresh install page because it freezes before that. I'll take the laptop to the PC shop, see what they can do.

Comment: It can still be that the CD is bad. But a PC shop is still the best idea.